# DI and IoC using Unity. Composition Root, Unit of Work DDD design considerations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Good day,

I need to verify if the following design makes sense:

DAL [EF 5 DbContext] => Entities

Entities [a separate assembly holding EF Entities.]

Services [things I want to do like CRUD etc] => DAL and =>Entities =>IServices

ISerivces [Interfaces for Services]

IoC [my Dependency factory with Unity container and static constructor] => IServices, Services. (Basically it ties interfaces to their implementation)

UI => IoC, IServices (and temporarily Entities and EF for I will use DTO's in my services thus eliminating the need for referencing EF).

There is no BAL or BLL - I am trying to put as much logic into my entities as possible (trough partial classes adding properties and methods, which perform BL). When this is absolutely impossible, some of the BL goes into Service (as little as possible though...).

Here's how I am using DI:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 

        var svc = DependencyFactory.Resolve<IMyService>();
        var l = svc.GetProjects();
}
```

Please,  if you have any comments as to if this design makes sense or not. Potential problems with extensibility/performance?

Also, this looks similar to the composition root pattern only that there it says that your IoC shouldn't be referenced anywhere. How do you then use it if it shouldn't be referenced?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Using your DI container outside of your composition root will most likely mean you are using the Service Locator (anti)Pattern. This couples your code tightly to your DI container, and will make unit testing hard, as service locators are usually static classes.

What you would want is to do constructor injection, where your dependencies are declared in the constructor.

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly IBar _bar;

    public Foo(IBar bar)
    {
        if (bar == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bar");
        }

        _bar = bar;
    }
}
```

You should then use Unity to resolve instance of Foo in your composition root, which will also take care of subsequent dependency chains.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning,

One thing to consider is that business logic tend to change very frequently. So I wouldn't split it between different assemblies if I were you because you don't necessarily want to recompile the assembly that was not intended to be recompiled after change to the BL.

In the ideal world your dependency would be resolved by web service of some kind (PS same thing should happen to business logic as well), but most of the times it's either impossible or takes lots of effort. In my previous project I had the dependency container (to resolve my dependencies) within services project which was referencing entities and whatnot.

Hope this helps,
Alex D